# Ionic app rendering incorrectly after camera opened

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 1 app that uses $cordovaCamera to retrieve a photo from the user. Oddly, after the camera is opened (doesn't matter whether the user takes a picture, cancels, or picks one from library) the app renders incorrectly once it's closed. The status bar overlays the top of the view, and the bottom of the view overflows off the viewport. However, if you re-orient the device (go from portrait to landscape) it will fix itself.

Is there any way to force the app to repaint manually?

Extra info regarding the bug itself: I created a new ionic 1 app separately and copied the camera code over exactly and it does not have the same problem. Same versions of ionic, angular, ngCordova, and the camera plugin. So I believe the actual rendering problem is specific to my app. However, after a full day of messing around I can't figure out for the life of me what's happening.

Comment: I ran into exact same problem.  Did you find a solution?  Did the answer below help?

Comment: I did! Just a couple days ago, in fact. I just posted it as an answer to be thorough

Answer (score 5):

We had the same issue with the cordova-plugin-statusbar version: **2.2.1**
The solution was pretty simple. We downgraded this dependency to version **2.2.0** and everything worked as expected again.

To use an exact version of a cordova plugin, specify it in the `config.xml` of your project as in example below:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.0"/>`

Don't forget to remove `./platforms` and  `./plugins` folders and to run `cordova prepare` after downgrading the plugin versions.

Comment: There is still the issue on 2.4.1, we had to downgrade to 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this plugin:
[cordova-plugin-hidden-statusbar-overlay](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-hidden-statusbar-overlay)

just install it, and after calling the camera, run this code:

```js
window.plugin.statusbarOverlay.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being pretty easy: REMOVE the status bar plugin.

I was under the impression that the status bar plugin was needed to make it appear at all but this is not the case. The StatusBar plugin only lets you style it - but since iOS 9 you can only choose from 2 options anyway.

1. Remove the status bar plugin completely. Don't forget to edit your bower.json, config.xml, the initialization code in your ionic app that sets StatusBar defaults, etc.
2. Add padding or margin to the top of your app when the `body` element has the class `platform-ios`. Per the Apple Developer Docs:

> Obscure content under the status bar. By default, the background of the status bar is transparent, allowing content beneath to show through. Keep the status bar readable and don’t imply that content behind it is interactive. There are several common techniques for doing this:
>   1) Use a navigation bar in your app, which automatically displays a status bar background and ensures that content doesn’t appear under the status bar.
>   2) Display a custom image, such as a gradient or solid color, behind the status bar.
>   3) Apply a blur to the content behind the status bar.

What you should end up with is the exact same appearance without the plugin.

Comment: Anyone experience or have a fix for Android doing this same behavior?